# vscode "vsintellicode.modify.editor.suggestSelection"

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

What does "vsintellicode.modify.editor.suggestSelection" configuration mean？

[image: setting]

Answer (score 0):

It's more of a "status" feedback rather than an option for the user to choose.
Quoting the Official docs issue about this:

> The value `automaticallyOverrodeDefaultValue` is intended to indicate that **IntelliCode has already done this in the past** (therefore overrode and not override). IntelliCode automatically overrode the default value for you previously. It's not really a user-selectable value on it's own, but it's more of a state keeping mechanism to help troubleshoot why the `editor.suggestSelection` value might have changed.

> `enabled` means you are allowing IntelliCode to change `editor.suggestSelection` on your behalf, but it hasn't done anything yet.

You can check a more complete description of this on an issue in  the official [intellicode docs](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/intellicode/issues/78#issuecomment-477694255).